# XamDataGrid: I have two columns (displaying decimal data): I want one with a "$" sign, and one without. How?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have two `decimal` datatype columns; I want them displayed like so:

- Column 1 (`ColumnWithNoDollarSign`) will have **no** "$" sign in front of the values
- Column 2 (`ColumnWithDollarSign`) will have a "$" sign in front of the values

This is what my XAML currently looks like:

```
<ig:XamDataGrid Name="xamDataGrid"                        
                IsGroupByAreaExpanded="False"
                DataSource="{Binding Rows, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ig:XamDataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Editors:XamNumericEditor}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Editors:XamCurrencyEditor}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
    </ig:XamDataGrid.Resources>
    <ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <ig:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"/>
    </ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <ig:FieldLayout Key="layout">
            <ig:Field Name="ColumnWithNoDollarSign" Label="Column 1"/>
            <ig:Field Name="ColumnWithDollarSign" Label="Column 1"/>
        </ig:FieldLayout>
    </ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</ig:XamDataGrid>
```

The problem, as I see it, is that the `XamCurrencyEditor` style I am applying is overriding all `decimal` columns. I only want it to override one of the `decimal` columns. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the XamNumericEditor represent the format without the $? If so, can you not just specify the style used by each column, ie do:

```
<ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    <ig:FieldLayout Key="layout">
        <ig:Field Name="ColumnWithNoDollarSign" Label="Column 1" Style="{StaticResource XamNumericEditor}"/>
        <ig:Field Name="ColumnWithDollarSign" Label="Column 1" Style="{StaticResource XamCurrencyEditor}"/>
    </ig:FieldLayout>
</ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```

Although I would recommend moving all style info to a single file, such as App.xaml, rather than re-defining it in multiple places.